# Замена N символов на пробелы в TXT файле через Regex в Notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Дано, таблица в ASCII формате, что-то вроде примера ниже

```
--------------+--------------+---------------
  сумма1      |    сумма2    |      итого    
              |              |               
--------------+--------------+---------------
       11     |       12     |      13       
--------------+--------------+---------------
          68209         100930         169139
          34923              0          34923
              0              0              0
         178139              0         178139
          39404         135802         175206
```

По задаче требуется найти диапазон символов в строке (это получилось) и заменить их на такое же количество пробелов (никак не могу понять, как организовать замену.

По примеру, возможно ли в Notepad++ сделать замену чисел в колонке 12 на пробелы?

Comment: все, что так сразу могу предложить, это запускать замену `^\s+\d+\s+\K\d(?=\d*\s+?\d+\s*?$)` на пробел столько раз, сколько символов в самом длинном числе

Comment: или селектнуть колонку с альтом, перенести в другое окно поменять все  цифры на пробелы и вернуть

Comment: Если вам необходимо делать выравнивание значений дописывая вперёд пробелы, то проще разбить строку со значениями на 3 секции и дописывать перед числом количество пробелов равное (длина колонки минус число знаков в числе). После склеиваете в строку и выводите. Но мне кажется, я неправильно понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: Это текстовый редактор, боюсь, ваш совет сложно будет применить

Comment: *это получилось* - Что у вас получилось? Покажите ваше выражение.

Comment: to Wiktor Stribiżew , поиск строки по выражению ".{106}$" (для примера будет 15 вместо 106 ).